# Why my ocaml program can't find module Clflags?

Tags: ocaml

I am new to ocaml,I found this page:
https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/

is this page the ocaml standard lib?

when I write a program with one line:

```
open Marshal
```

ocamlc can build it

when I write

```
open Clflags
```

ocamlc give me error:Unbound module Cflags

but Clflags and Marshal are both in the list of this page

when I try to install Clflags with opam,opam tell me can't find this package

So how to use package Clflags?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cflags` is a module, that belongs to the `compiler-libs` library, a library for compiler developers and those who are extending the compiler. So most likely, you're looking into a wrong module.

To use it, you need to add the `compiler-libs` folder to the search path and specify the library name that provides this module. Some automation tools will do this for you, but on the low level (for native compilation) this will look like this (assuming that your code is in the `test.ml` file):

```
ocamlopt -I +compiler-libs ocamlcommon.cmxa test.ml  -o test
```

Comment: Thanks.is there any way to let vscode not report error when I write open Clflags or other not stdlib packages?

Comment: create an `.merlin` file, and specify libraries that you're using with the following syntax:
PKG <libname>

See more, there - https://github.com/ocaml/merlin/wiki/project-configuration

Answer (score 1):

This is not the index of the standard library, but the index of all modules provided by the standard distribution, including the compiler's front-end modules, which `Clflags` is a part of.

You can get the list of the standard library's modules [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/stdlib.html#sec552), and the "core", always opened module [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html).

`Clflags` isn't really useful unless you are hacking the compiler itself, which isn't really the best task for a beginner. You can find [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/parsing.html) in the documentation how to compile with it:

```
ocamlc other options -I +compiler-libs ocamlcommon.cma other files
```

But then again, you don't want to do it until you have a good grasp on OCaml and its compiler.